# jQuery Validation Engine Always Return True in Asp.Net Web Forms

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms, jquery-validation-engine

i have used jquery validation engine in my project with correct references(source in masterpage). I have a page which inherits from master page and the form is;

```
        <tr>
            <td class="shade">
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="LiteralSession" Text="Year" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textBoxSession" 
                    CssClass="validate[required]" 
                    data-validation-placeholder="e.g 2012-2013" />
            </td>
        </tr>
                <td style="height: 30px">
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="buttonRegister" Text="Register" ValidationGroup="R"
                        OnClick="Btn_Register_Click" />
                </td>
```

In `document.ready()` i am testing whether the validation engine has errors or not;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#formMain").validationEngine('attach', { scroll: true });
            $('#buttonRegister').click(function (evt) {
                var isValid = $('#formMain').validationEngine('validate');
                if (!isValid) {
                    alert("not valid");
                    evt.preventDefault();
                }
                else {
                    alert("valid");
                }
            });
        });
```

However, **when i post this form, it return true**, when i don't type something in the **textbox**. 
So, Why the `jQuery Validation Engine` doesn't detecting the `textBoxSession` for errors?
**Update:** I am also using update panel in my master page which wraps all the content placeholders including this (the above html codes)

Comment: Did you add the `action="submit.action"` attribute in `<form id="formID" method="post" action="submit.action">`?

Comment: i am using webforms (asp.net). So this doesn't work     `<form id="formMain" runat="server" method="post" action="submit.action">`

Comment: I'm not sure how your html will be generated by your setup, will changing `$("#formMain")` to `$('form')` works? Your form id might be changed by the html generator.

Comment: i saw the source view, the `id="formMain"`

Comment: i tried the $('form') but still not working

Comment: It will be helpful if the html from view source is copied here.

Comment: You can set the submit behavior on the asp.net button with UseSubmitBehavior="true"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior%28v=vs.110%29.aspx